# Stencil in blitz++ 0.10

Tags: c++, blitz++

I'm trying to use the stencil object from Blitz++ User Guide

```
#include <blitz/array.h>
using namespace blitz;

BZ_DECLARE_STENCIL4(test,P1,P2,P3,c)
    P3 = 2 * P2 + c * Laplacian3D(P2) - P1;
BZ_END_STENCIL

applyStencil(test(), P1, P2, P3, c);
```

But after compilation I have this error

```
test_blitz.cpp: In static member function ‘static void test::apply(T1&, T2&, T3&, T4&, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11) [with T1 = blitz::FastArrayIterator<long double, 3>, T2 = blitz::FastArrayIterator<long double, 3>, T3 = blitz::FastArrayIterator<long double, 3>, T4 = blitz::FastArrayIterator<long double, 3>, T5 = blitz::dummy<double>, T6 = blitz::dummy<double>, T7 = blitz::dummy<double>, T8 = blitz::dummy<double>, T9 = blitz::dummy<double>, T10 = blitz::dummy<double>, T11 = blitz::dummy<double>]’:
/usr/include/blitz/array/stencils.cc:288:13:   instantiated from ‘void blitz::applyStencil_imp(const T_stencil&, blitz::Array<T_numtype1, 3>&, T_array2&, T_array3&, T_array4&, T_array5&, T_array6&, T_array7&, T_array8&, T_array9&, T_array10&, T_array11&) [with T_stencil = test, T_numtype1 = long double, T_array2 = blitz::Array<long double, 3>, T_array3 = blitz::Array<long double, 3>, T_array4 = blitz::Array<long double, 3>, T_array5 = blitz::dummyArray, T_array6 = blitz::dummyArray, T_array7 = blitz::dummyArray, T_array8 = blitz::dummyArray, T_array9 = blitz::dummyArray, T_array10 = blitz::dummyArray, T_array11 = blitz::dummyArray]’
/usr/include/blitz/array/stencils.cc:535:5:   instantiated from ‘void blitz::applyStencil(const T_stencil&, blitz::Array<T_numtype1, N_rank>&, T_array2&, T_array3&, T_array4&) [with T_stencil = test, T_numtype1 = long double, int N_rank = 3, T_array2 = blitz::Array<long double, 3>, T_array3 = blitz::Array<long double, 3>, T_array4 = blitz::Array<long double, 3>]’
test_blitz.cpp:35:36:   instantiated from here
test_blitz.cpp:9:5: error: ‘Laplacian3D’ was not declared in this scope
```

Other array operations (multiplication, where and etc.) are working. Can anybody explain what am I doing wrong?

**UPD**

It looks like I'm missed the header `blitz/array/stencil-et.h` (which is in example `stencil2.cpp`), but there is another error

```
test_blitz.cpp: In static member function ‘static void test::apply(T1&, T2&, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11) [with T1 = blitz::FastArrayIterator<long double, 3>, T2 = blitz::FastArrayIterator<long double, 3>, T3 = blitz::dummy<double>, T4 = blitz::dummy<double>, T5 = blitz::dummy<double>, T6 = blitz::dummy<double>, T7 = blitz::dummy<double>, T8 = blitz::dummy<double>, T9 = blitz::dummy<double>, T10 = blitz::dummy<double>, T11 = blitz::dummy<double>]’:
/usr/include/blitz/array/stencils.cc:288:13:   instantiated from ‘void blitz::applyStencil_imp(const T_stencil&, blitz::Array<T_numtype1, 3>&, T_array2&, T_array3&, T_array4&, T_array5&, T_array6&, T_array7&, T_array8&, T_array9&, T_array10&, T_array11&) [with T_stencil = test, T_numtype1 = long double, T_array2 = blitz::Array<long double, 3>, T_array3 = blitz::dummyArray, T_array4 = blitz::dummyArray, T_array5 = blitz::dummyArray, T_array6 = blitz::dummyArray, T_array7 = blitz::dummyArray, T_array8 = blitz::dummyArray, T_array9 = blitz::dummyArray, T_array10 = blitz::dummyArray, T_array11 = blitz::dummyArray]’
/usr/include/blitz/array/stencils.cc:515:5:   instantiated from ‘void blitz::applyStencil(const T_stencil&, blitz::Array<T_numtype1, N_rank>&, T_array2&) [with T_stencil = test, T_numtype1 = long double, int N_rank = 3, T_array2 = blitz::Array<long double, 3>]’
test_blitz.cpp:38:30:   instantiated from here
test_blitz.cpp:12:5: error: no matching function for call to ‘Laplacian3D(blitz::FastArrayIterator<long double, 3>&)’
test_blitz.cpp:12:5: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/blitz/array/stencil-classes.cc:15348:3: note: template<class T1> blitz::_bz_ArrayExpr<blitz::Laplacian3D_et<typename blitz::asExpr<T>::T_expr::T_range_result, typename blitz::asExpr<T>::T_expr::T_numtype> > blitz::Laplacian3D(const blitz::ETBase<T>&)
/usr/include/blitz/array/stencil-classes.cc:15356:3: note: template<class T, int N> blitz::_bz_ArrayExpr<blitz::Laplacian3D_et<typename blitz::asExpr<blitz::Array<T, N> >::T_expr::T_range_result, T> > blitz::Laplacian3D(const blitz::Array<T, N>&)
/usr/include/blitz/array/stencil-classes.cc:15361:3: note: template<class T, int N> blitz::_bz_ArrayExpr<blitz::Laplacian3D_et<typename blitz::asExpr<blitz::Array<T, N> >::T_expr::T_range_result, T> > blitz::Laplacian3D(blitz::Array<T, N>&)
```

Any ideas?

Link to the full example of code with error message https://gist.github.com/erthalion/8784150

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a #include I think.  Perhaps `#include <blitz/array/stencilops.h>`, or grep through the blitz headers on your system to find Laplacian3D.

Comment: You're right, but there is the one more error - I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
BZ_DECLARE_STENCIL4(test,P1,P2,P3,c)
    P3 = 2 * P2 + c * Laplacian3D(P2) - P1;
BZ_END_STENCIL
```

Try using

```
BZ_DECLARE_STENCIL4(test,P1,P2,P3,c)
    P3 = 2 * P2 + c * Laplacian3D_stencilop(P2) - P1;
BZ_END_STENCIL
```

My understanding is that `Laplacian` is a stencil (like the one you are declaring), and `Laplacian3D_stencilop` is a stencil operator (like a difference operator) that you can use inside your own stencil object.